# Displaying geojson data on a map after submiting form using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm trying to display data on a leaflet map based on a form selector. My problem is that the data are not displayed after selecting the option.

I have an html file `webiste.html`, and two php files `insert_data.php` and `read_data.php` (might not be the most efficient thing in the world).

This is my selector :

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <select onchange="submitForm(); changeData()" value="false" name="geo" id="geo" class="selectors myDropdown">
        <option value="base">Geo</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

These are the js functions that are activated when an option is selected :

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([45.505, -73.19], 9); // Set initial coordinates and zoom level
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'}).addTo(map);

//Submit the data and populate my postgresql table
//This one works
function submitForm() {
    var formData = {
        geo: $("#geo").val(),
    };
    console.log(formData)
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert_data.php",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        encode: true,
    }).done(function (data) {
    });
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

```
//read the data
function changeData(){
    var geoSelect = document.getElementById('geo');
    geo.setAttribute("value", "true")
    var geoSelect = document.getElementById('geo').getAttribute('value');
    if (geoSelect == 'true'){
        $.get("refresh_query.php", function(data){
        }); //this reset my postgresql table
        $.ajax({url:'read_data.php', //This is what seems to be the issue
            success: function(response){
            airbnbs = JSON.parse(response)
            lyr = L.geoJSON(airbnbs,{
            }).addTo(map)
            }   
        })
        var geoSelect = document.getElementById('geo');
        geoSelect.setAttribute("value", "false")
    }else{
    }
}
```

Finally, this is my `read_data.php` script :

```
<?php
$db = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=db user=postgres password=xxxxx");

if (!$db) {
    echo "An error occurred.\n";
    exit;
}


$sql = 'SELECT id, ST_AsGeoJSON((ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng, lat), 4326)), 4) as geom 
        FROM data';

//pg_query("DELETE FROM data");
$query = pg_exec($db, $sql);
$features = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < pg_numrows($query); $i++) {
    $row = pg_fetch_assoc($query,$i);
    $geometry = $row['geom'] = json_decode($row['geom']);
    unset($row['geom']);
    // Nous retirons les résultats redondants
    unset($row[0]);
    unset($row[1]);
    unset($row[2]);
    unset($row[3]);
    unset($row[4]);
    // Nous reconstituons notre 'feature' sur le modèle GeoJSON
    $feature = ['type' => 'Feature', 'geometry' => $geometry, 'properties' => $row];
    array_push($features, $feature);
};
$featureCollection = ["type" => "FeatureCollection", "features" => $features];
echo stripslashes(json_encode($featureCollection, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
pg_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: _"My problem is that the data are not displayed after selecting the option."_ - what happens instead? Have you _debugged_ the code? My guess would be that `event.preventDefault();` is probably not working as intended here; you would be relying on the global `event` object - which you shouldn't do. My suggestion would be that you replace those inline event handler attributes, with proper jquery event handling, first of all.